# grep Extract any sequence of numbers that is longer than 10 digits from each line

Tags: grep

I am new to [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and have used a couple times. I am now on a new project where I have txt or excel files that have records that have similar format to below. There are thousands of records and all have different formats, so I need a way to just pull any and all 10 digit numbers it finds in each record and put those 10 digit numbers in to a new txt file.

```
/20180130124137_7602053275_13362514943
```

another example

```
/20180130-084548_3109217528
```

The end result I am looking for would be for the new file to have added `7602053275` from the first record above as that is the only 10 digit number in that record and `3109217528` from the second example above. 
Thanks,

Comment: So what is stopping you from doing that? You said you used `grep`, care to show us what you tried?

Comment: also, title says `longer than 10 digits` while the sample indicates `exactly 10 digits`

Comment: Ya I need code for extracting any 10 digit number that is in a file and the records in file will look like above samples. So what is Grep code I can use to extract all 10 digit numbers from each record from file? I would like them put in to a new text file. Thx